# My LinkedIn Webscraper seems to only be navigating to the log on page rather than the page chosen after logging in

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have created a webscraper using the code below, and I am trying to log in and then extract the post data for the specified company. When I attempt this, my dataframe returns empty, hence I tried printing the results at each stage to understand what was occurring. I have found that it seems to not be logging into the website correctly and so stays on the log on page and scrapes that rather than the companies page.

```
#Import relevant packages
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
import pandas as pd
import re as re
# Install chromium, its driver, and selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium
# set options to be headless, ..
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# open it, go to a website, and get results
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/rm/sign-in-another-account')
time.sleep(3)

# locate email form by_class_name
username = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
# send_keys() to simulate key strokes
username.send_keys(email)
# locate password form by_class_name
password = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
# send_keys() to simulate key strokes
password.send_keys(password)
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


# Go to webpage
page = "https://www.linkedin.com/company/cgi/"
browser.get(page + 'posts/')

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1.5

# Scroll webpage
height = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " + str(height) + ");")

company_page = browser.page_source   

linkedin_soup = bs(company_page.encode("utf-8"), "html")
linkedin_soup.prettify()

containers = linkedin_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"occludable-update ember-view"})

post_dates = []
post_texts = []

for container in containers:

    try:
        posted_date = container.find("span",{"class":"visually-hidden"})
        text_box = container.find("div",{"class":"feed-shared-update-v2__description-wrapper"})
        text = text_box.find("span",{"dir":"ltr"})
    
        post_dates.append(posted_date.text.strip())
        post_texts.append(text.text.strip())

    except:
        pass

data = {
    "Date Posted": post_dates,
    "Post Text": post_texts,
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

print("this is soup")
print(linkedin_soup)
print("these are dates")
print(post_dates)
print("these are texts")
print(post_texts)
```

This is the output:

```
this is soup
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta content="auth_wall_desktop_company" name="pageKey"/>
<!-- --> <meta content="en_US" name="locale"/>
<meta data-app-version="2.0.175" data-browser-id="1cee17d3-c025-4bb5-8a44-2792146e4835" data-call-tree-id="AAXQij/e9oXWhSYHn1NLlg==" data-enable-core-web-tracking="" data-enable-page-view-heartbeat-tracking="" data-multiproduct-name="seo-directory-frontend" data-service-name="seo-directory-frontend" id="config"/>
<link href="/authwall" rel="canonical"/>
<!-- --><!-- -->
<!-- -->
<!-- -->
<!-- -->
<link href="https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/al2o9zrvru7aqj8e1x2rzsrca" rel="icon"/>
<script>
            function getDfd() {let yFn,nFn;const p=new Promise(function(y, n){yFn=y;nFn=n;});p.resolve=yFn;p.reject=nFn;return p;}
            window.lazyloader = getDfd();
            window.tracking = getDfd();
            window.impressionTracking = getDfd();
            window.ingraphTracking = getDfd();
            window.appDetection = getDfd();
            window.pemTracking = getDfd();
          </script>
<!-- -->
<title>
        Sign In | LinkedIn
      </title>
<link href="/authwall" rel="canonical"/>
<meta content="750 million+ members | Manage your professional identity. Build and engage with your professional network. Access knowledge, insights and opportunities." name="description"/>
<meta content="noindex, noarchive" name="robots"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/>
<meta content="en_US" name="locale"/>
<meta content="Sign Up | LinkedIn" property="og:title"/>
<meta content="https://static-exp1.licdn.com/scds/common/u/images/logos/favicons/v1/favicon.ico" property="og:image"/>
<meta content="website" property="og:type"/>
<meta content="/authwall" property="og:url"/>
<meta content="summary" name="twitter:card"/>
<meta content="@Linkedin" name="twitter:site"/>
<meta content="Sign Up | LinkedIn" name="twitter:title"/>
<meta content="https://static-exp1.licdn.com/scds/common/u/images/logos/favicons/v1/favicon.ico" name="twitter:image"/>
<meta content="https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/bxullzz73p3hhf78t6sj3w6pb" name="platform-worker"/>
<meta content="seo-directory-frontend" name="litmsProfileName"/>
<meta content="1" data-counter-metric-endpoint="/directory/api/ingraphs/counter" data-gauge-metric-endpoint="/directory/api/ingraphs/gauge" name="clientSideIngraphs"/>
<script src="https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/bepk06p6ynqyomnc9e69zx02u"></script></head></html>
these are dates
[]
these are texts
[]
```

Would you be able to suggest why this might be the issue, or if there is another method of login which I can use? I previously tried using the LinkedIn API but I had some difficulties implementing this using the secret key and token, hence I opted for the simpler password option as I had seen this used in other tutorials.

Comment: Why are you logging in to a website and then opening a new page (in which you need to login)? Also, don't post you username and password here.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about that. I thought it would be the best way to log on. But I'm guessing it is better to just go to one webpage directly?

Comment: Yes, you can just call `browser.get` on `page` and then you can locate the username and password element.